# AngularJs , NodeJs Routing Issue

Tags: node.js, angularjs

My application is based on NodeJs & AngularJs SPA. I ran into routing issues. The application is complex. To make it easier to explain the problem , I created a trivial todo application.

Node server code ( server.js)

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    publicPath  = path.normalize(__dirname + '/public'),
    Todos = require('./Todo');

var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.session({secret: 'This is Top secret'}));
    app.use(express.static(publicPath));
});

app.get('/api/Todos',Todos.getTodos);
app.get('/api/Todos/:id',Todos.getById);
app.put('/api/Todos/:id', Todos.update);
app.post('/api/Todos/:id', Todos.create);
app.delete('/api/Todos/:id', Todos.delete);

app.all('/api/*', function(req, res) {
    res.send(404);
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(publicPath+'/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000);

console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

AngularJs routing related code ( app.js)

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

angular.module('app').config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $routeProvider
  .when('/', { templateUrl: 'views/home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl'})
  .when('/Todos', { templateUrl: 'views/todo.list.html', controller: 'TodoListCtrl'    })   
  .when('/Todos/Edit/:id', { templateUrl: 'views/todo.edit.html', controller: 'TodoEditCtrl' })
  .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});
```

In this /Todos route works but /Todos/Edit/:id route does not work. If I navigate to that route through href / ng-href the browser hangs and later it crashes.

I'm clueless. Kindly guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried injecting `['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', ` before your function call in the config ? (It's probably not that, but worth a try). Don't forget to close the square bracket.

Comment: Got it solved with the help of answer by @jdobry at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240288/angularjs-and-nodejs-express-routes-and-refresh . The solution is add a '/' before 'views' in 'templateUrl'

Comment: @Goodzilla Thank You for your interest & time.