# Pass an Array to $resource with POST method using Angularjs Expressjs Node and MEAN.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I want to pass an array to $save in $resource method and then receive it in my server controller to modify the data in database.

I can pass a variable in GET and it works just fine!
But my array which I want to pass seem like is not working!

I do not receive any Error in my console.
I am using MEAN.js and both POST and GET requests seems like working (green 200 ) but when I call req.body.variable1 to access the variable which I passed by $save method it is not working.

Can I have both POST and GET method at same page?

I will appreciate any help or hint which will lead to correct answer for this.
Thanks!

Resource Factory

```
angular.module('alls').factory('Alls', ['$resource', function($resource) {

return $resource('alls/:issuename', {issuename: '@issuename'},
    {

        get:{ method: 'GET', isArray:true }

    });
}]);
```

Client Controller

```
angular.module('alls').controller('AllsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Alls',
function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Alls ) {


    $scope.search = function(){

        Alls.get({issuename: $scope.issueinput},function(response){
            $scope.alls = response;

        });

        var myArray = new Alls ({
            variable1: 'Blue',
            variable2: 'Red'
        });

        myArray.$save();
    };

} ]);
```

Server Route

```
module.exports = function(app) {
var alls = require('../../app/controllers/alls.server.controller');

app.route('/alls')
    .get(alls.list)
    .post(alls.list);

app.route('/alls/:issuename')
    .get(alls.list)
    .post(alls.list);       app.param('issuename', alls.searchfun);  };
```

Server Controller

```
    exports.searchfun = function(req, res, next, id) {
    req.alpha = id;
    next();
    };


exports.list = function(req, res) {

   var colorVar = req.body.variable1;
   var searchParam = req.alpha;

   mongoose.model(searchParam).find({ color: colorVar }).sort('-created').exec(function(err, alls) {
       res.jsonp(alls);
   });   };
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your $resource url and your $route's don't match. Depending on your folder structure you will need to either add a slash to your $resource url like this...

```js
return $resource('/alls/:issuename', {issuename: '@issuename'},
    {

        get:{ method: 'GET', isArray:true }

    });
}]);
```

...or (more likely) fix your routes. See this answer for reference... 
[AngularJS and nodeJs Express: routes and refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240288/angularjs-and-nodejs-express-routes-and-refresh/18257715#18257715)